# JQuery error during load "Failed to execute query: '*,:x' is not a valid selector."

Tags: jquery

I am trying to debug an application and I can't start because I am getting an error as the browser is loading jquery 2.1.0.  The error is on line 1210 of the unminified version

```
div.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
```

and I am getting the error in the title.

I am using Chrome version 32.

Comment: what are you trying to do with `:x`

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't think it's his code. Sounds like jQuery's code is doing it. OP, have you tried re-downloading jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running jQuery crashing on IE10/Win7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145108/running-jquery-crashing-on-ie10-win7)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I've found this [jQuery bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13881) that seems like what you're experiencing, another one on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145108/running-jquery-crashing-on-ie10-win7) describing the problem and a [longer discussion about it on another jQuery bug ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14123#comment:7).

Although, it seems like it's *not* tagged as a bug as it's jQuery's internal error checking/exceptions being thrown.

As the comment by [jQuery team describes](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13881#comment:1):

> Resolution set to **notabug**
>
> Don't break on caught exceptions. We caught it because we *expected* it.

Comment: I want to slap myself in the forehead very hard. I was dealing with a project that isn't using jQuery and had 'Pause On Caught Exceptions' in Chrome's DevTools, then returned to an older project and wasted one hour because of this.

Comment: This is definitely a bug, in that it impedes the debugging process when dealing with other caught exceptions.  It would be great if there was a way to fix the jQuery code to prevent this infinite throwing and catching of exceptions.

Comment: @KamenMinkov Don't feel too bad, I just made literally exactly the same mistake as you. It took me the same amount of time as well until I stumbled on this helpful response.

Comment: Yes, it impedes the debugging process substantially for me, and has for months. Every time some library eats an exception I want the context info for, I enable that "pause on caught exceptions". Then I reload the page, and see JQuery block my intention with 4 pauses each launch. -_-   (and this is less than in my other project)

Comment: it's not a bug in jQuery per se, it's part of jQuery needing to function across browsers and platforms that in turn have various bugs. in this case they need to know if a browser throws an error or not, where not throwing is an incorrect behavior, but they still need to handle that. in other words, the correct behavior is this exception, but some browsers don't throw it, and jQuery needs to know that.

Comment: granted, they should be able to figure out a way to inform you what's going on a little faster, such as an exception message that references a URL with an explanation, or something along those lines. as things stand, this appears to be an unavoidable part of the learning curve of using jQuery.

Comment: Soemtimes the reality is you just can't detect things until an exception is thrown. For a library like jQuery this is almost certainly unavoidable in some parts... If this is hindering your own debugging though I find that blackboxing the script in your devtools works wonders (at least in Chrome).

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem on Firefox 57.

The ["breaking on exceptions" documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Breaking_on_exceptions) tells us that "pause button (II)" has *three* states. The **light purple state** is the one that we want: It shows uncaught exceptions, but ignores caught ones.

Comment: This lead to the solution for me. Under the "pause button (||)" there is a checkbox for "Pause on caught exceptions". Unchecking it frees up debugging flow.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using **Visual studio code** for debugging, just make the All Exception unchecked in the breakpoints section .

Answer (score 1):

Just to add what I found on Chrome/OSX in a particular scenario.  I found this using `.is(':visible')`

It shows up in the log when it is called from a function executed in a setTimeout() but works just fine.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Failed to execute 'matches' on 'Element': ':visible' is not a valid selector.
```

I'm not sure the reason, but I pulled the use of `setTimeout` and moved on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception and resolved it by just turning off the javascript exceptions in Visual Studio 2022
In Visual Studio: go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings
in the opening window uncheck the Javascript Exceptions

Comment: Why do you think ignoring a problem is a reasonable fix for that issue?

Answer (score -3):

I had the same issue and solved it by restarting the browser. It seems to have disappeared.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem too, drove me nearly nuts. I spent 3 days on this. Check out the following:

Body height. Not just the css height, but also physically check the height, I use mozilla firebug to select the body attribute, this highlightes it. If it's above the element, or selection area, it will give the bug.
Also css for the specific area to select, and body

```
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
Make sure your user selection is !!NOT!! none.
```

Hope this helps you out.. I did read some very frustrating posts regarding this issue, and it was not an easy find either, I found it quite by chance.

Answer (score -5):

The [`*`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) selector selects **all elements**, therefore combining it with other selectors, e.g. `*,div`, is unnecessary.