# jquery error n invalid selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have that line of code:

```
  const actions = $('.leaflet-draw-actions a:visible').length;
```

that trigers many errors:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.leaflet-draw-actions a:visible' is not a valid selector.
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (...\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:869:1)
```

I would like to select all link visible children of the **.leaflet-draw-actions** div.

Do you know of a better valid selector?

Comment: For some reason Sizzle didn't realize it's not a real psuedo selector `:visible` and handed it off to qSA.

Comment: Why not simply `const actions = $('.leaflet-draw-actions').children('a:visible');`?

Comment: What happens if you do `$('.leaflet-draw-actions a').filter(":visible")`?

Comment: Try `:not([hidden])` instead of `:visible`.

Comment: if its a div you can use const actions = $('div.leaflet-draw-actions a').length;

Comment: Possible dupe [JQuery error during load “Failed to execute query: '*,:x' is not a valid selector.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21661113/jquery-error-during-load-failed-to-execute-query-x-is-not-a-valid-selecto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official documentation:

> Because `:visible` is a **jQuery** extension and not part of the **CSS**
>   specification, queries using `:visible` cannot take advantage of the
>   performance boost provided by the native **DOM** `querySelectorAll()`
>   method. To achieve the best performance when using `:visible` to select
>   elements, first select the elements using a pure **CSS** selector, then
>   use `.filter(":visible")`.

And it obviously tries to call `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Usually Sizzle is smart enough to understand that and leverage qSA where it can and otherwise use its own filtering.

Comment: Well, not this time I guess