# jquery DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element'

Tags: jquery

please help. When I add jquery to almost empty site, it shows me this:

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element':
>   '*,:x' is not a valid selector.
>       at Error (native)
>       at http://localhost/Sites/Humator/www/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:10517
>       at ia (http://localhost/Sites/Humator/www/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:7373)
>       at fa.setDocument (http: //localhost/Sites/Humator/www/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:10255)
>       at http: //localhost/Sites/Humator/www/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:22073
>       at http: //localhost/Sites/Humator/www/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:22793
>       at http: //localhost/Sites/Humator/www/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:207
>       at http: //localhost/Sites/Humator/www/assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:212

I don't have a clue what is it, because my site is without any queries now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">var plugin_path = 'assets/plugins/';</script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix it please? I use Chrome - latest version

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145108/running-jquery-crashing-on-ie10-win7

Answer (score 1):

jQuery determines which browser you're using by seeing which exceptions it throws. In this case:

```
// Opera 10-11 does not throw on post-comma invalid pseudos
el.querySelectorAll("*,:x");
rbuggyQSA.push(",.*:");
```

So all you need to do is set your debugger to "ignore caught exceptions".